# Can't access to localhost from other computer (BeEFProject)

Tags: ruby, networking, xampp

I've run [beef](http://beefproject.com/) on my localhost, a couple of testing and it's working very good but when I was trying to access from a virtual machine using XP It's only loading the page forever I only can see the title in the tab bar next to the favicon but no more else. My firewall is off and my XAMPP is running. In addition if I want to access to all my projects in XAMPP I can do it from this virtual machine. So the problem seems to be only when I trying to access to the 3000 port that use beefproject. Some about beefproject [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdbvU_U42kY).

FYI: Is working vert good with the WIFI shared from my computer to the iphone.

Comment: Make sure your virtual machines are set to use "bridged adapter" and not "nat". If you change this while the machine is running, make sure to stop and start your NIC on the virtual machine.

Comment: It's working! thanks! What is the diferent between "bridged adapter" and "nat"